# Why does System.Data.Linq generates ROW_NUMBER() for Paging instead of OFFSET/FETCH for SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, linq-to-sql

We are using Linq and Entity Framework to access a SQL Server 2012 database. We are having some performance issue, so after some investigation, we were able to fix some of the problems, but I would like to use SQL query with `OFFSET/FETCH` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` and `BETWEEN` syntax.

The performance difference is not so big. `OFFSET/FETCH` is quicker by about 10%. Do you have any idea why the generated query uses `ROW_NUMBER()` and `BETWEEN` syntax? What can I do to force Linq to generate `OFFSET/FETCH` query?

C# code:

```
var orders = dc.Orders.OrderBy(q => q.LastModifiedTimestamp)
                      .Skip(q => skipCount)
                      .Take(q => takeCount)
                      .ToList();
```

The currently generated query:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 10
DECLARE @p1 Int = 10
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[OrderId], [t2].[CustomerId]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t1].[OrderId], [t1].[CustomerId]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[OrderId], [t0].[CustomerId]
        FROM [Order] AS [t0]
        ) AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE [t2].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
ORDER BY [t2].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

The preferred query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Order]
ORDER BY LastModifiedTimestamp
    OFFSET 10000 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

Do you have any idea why the generated query use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `BETWEEN` syntax? What can I do to force Linq to generate `OFFSET/FETCH` query?

Comment: Wrong target version in your EDMX?

Comment: I was trying to find EDMX files, but it is not presented in the solution.

Comment: Also if I put the c# code to LinqPad, it generates the query with ROW_NUMBER() and BETWEEN

Comment: You should look into [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) it's much better than offset pagination. Basically you start your scan based on the highest key of the previous page

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this?